# Getting parse error while running terraform validate. How to Fix

Tags: terraform

i have setup terraform and i am getting parse error while running terraform validate. how to fix this.

i am running Terraform v0.11.9 and facing parse error while running terraform validate

```
 provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sshpass -f /work/pwdfile.tfvars ssh -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking=no\" -t ${var.username1}@${self.resource_configuration.${var.catalog_name}.ip_address} \"echo $(cat /work/pwdfile.tfvars) | sudo -S yum update -y\""


    }


expected result should pass terraform validate but actual output is 

parse error at 1:117: expected "}" but found invalid sequence "$"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to do with double `$`?

it need be escaped

Comment: could you please tell me where i need to add double $. i tried in couple of places. but not working..